# I can't find the Directory browsing in IIS Manager

Tags: asp.net, iis

So I was using vs 2013 and creating an ASP.NET app when I always get this error 403.14 whenever I try to debug run my project
[image: my error]

so i searched youtube and fouond that I needed to enable Directory Browsing in IIS Manager.

[image: The tutorial says]

When I got there, I couldn't find the Directory Browser

[image]

It might be something I accidentally misconfigured here but i really dont know
[image]

Please help me, I really want to use vs 2013 in my project instead of 2010.

Comment: Check in Turn Windows Features On or Off, is this enable or not `Internet Information Services / World Wide Web Services / Common HTTP Features /Directory Browsing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Windows Features is On for 'Directory Browsing'.

You can find it on this path:
`Information Services / World Wide Web Services / Common HTTP Features /Directory Browsing`.